# Python: get the value of a checkbox in Excel

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a checkbox called "check1" in an Excel file and I would like to take its value with Python.

I tried:

```
 wb = load_workbook(filename=myFile, read_only=True, data_only=True)
 title, coord = next(wb.defined_names['check1'].destinations)

 valueCheck1= wb[title][coord].value
```

with openpyxl but it does not work.

The error is:

> KeyError: 'No definition called check1'

even if I have properly defined it

Any suggestion?

Comment: You obviously haven't got the right name otherwise you wouldn't get a `KeyError`

Comment: Actually the name is exactly the same (I did ctrl+c ctrl+v) imho it could depend on the fact that checkbox is considered as a shape and is not recognized with defined_names.

Comment: `wb.defined_names.names` will give you a list of the constants for the workbook.

Comment: It does not appear between them. Probably because it is a shape

Comment: That might explain it, yes. There's no reason for it to be in the list and openpyxl does not yet support reading drawings.

Comment: Ok so a solution could be to link its value to a cell and take that value?